# Why am i getting this error (swift 2.2, dealing with func and named parameters)?

Tags: swift, swift2

This code is written in Xcode 7.3. I can't figure out why i'm getting this error. In swift 1.0 it was working fine. But in swift 2.2 it is not.

[image: image desc]

Comment: Hi, you should include the code in your question and any error message you get.

Comment: Refrain yourself from linking to external images of code. This code is not searchable and is not convenient for anyone to access and read. Please post the code itself in your question and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot use `#` for parameter names anymore in Swift. If you want the external parameter to share the same name as the internal one - you'll have to write it twice.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but title says "Swift 2.0", yet tagged with `swift2.2`...

Comment: @NicolasMiari you can edit the title ;)

Comment: I know... Pedantic _and_ lazy :-)

Comment: Have you tried using the migration tool on your code? (Edit menu > Convert > To latest Swift syntax)

Comment: Thank you guys. New to posting in this forum. Your comments've been pretty helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Swift 2.x documentation:

> **Local and External Parameter Names for Methods**
>
> Function parameters can have both a local name (for use within the
>   function’s body) and an external name (for use when calling the
>   function), as described in Specifying External Parameter Names. The
>   same is true for method parameters, because methods are just functions
>   that are associated with a type.
>
> ...
>
> **Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter
>   name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names
>   both local and external parameter names by default**. This convention
>   matches the typical naming and calling convention you will be familiar
>   with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for expressive method
>   calls without the need to qualify your parameter names.

---

To match exactly the Swift 1.0 syntax in your screenshot you have to write

```
func isDivisible(divided divided: Int, divisor: Int) -> Bool {}
```

By the way: `if divided % divisor` does not compile, you can replace the whole function body by

```
return divided % divisor == 0
```

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The below should work as expected:

```
func isDivisible(divided: Int, divisor: Int) -> Bool {
    if divided % divisor == 0 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: `divided % divisor` returns an `Int` in this case so it wouldn't work.

Comment: Oops i missed the '==0'